# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. 3

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute 2 `SELECT` queries.

I have the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.USERNUMBER, B.USERNAME
    (SELECT 
         B.USERNUMBER, COUNT(1) 
     FROM B
     INNER JOIN A ON B.USERNUMBER = A.USERNUMBER
     WHERE 
         A.USERNUMBER = B.USERNUMBER 
         AND B.PBALANCE <> '0' 
          OR B.IBALANCE <> '0' 
          OR B.SCBALANCE <> '0' 
     GROUP BY B.USERNUMBER)
FROM 
    A
INNER JOIN 
    B ON A.USERNUMBER = B.USERNUMBER
WHERE  
    A.USERNUMBER = B.USERNUMBER
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parent query and child query has table name same and subquery has been return one column not multiple

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```
SELECT a,b,..,(SELECT ... ), g, h,....
```

the second 'SELECT' in parens, the subquery, is contributing one column to your result, just like `a`, 'b', etc. Therefore it can have only one column it **its** select clause.